# Oracle SQL select where like value of row

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have 2 tables:

festival table: with column **NAME**

```
---------------------
NAME
---------------------
1. ultra music
2. coachella
```

and Querydata with column: **QUERY**

```
----------------------
QUERY
----------------------
1. xyz
2. coachella festival
3. abc
4. ultra music festival
```

So I want to count all the occurrences of each festival in the `querydata` table.

I mean I could go through the `Querydata` table and search for every single festival name on it's own but I'm really looking for convenient way to do this.

```
SELECT QUERY FROM QUERYDATA 
WHERE QUERY LIKE '%coachella%'
AND QUERY LIKE '%festival%'
```

Please help me I'm really stuck on this one !
Cheers

Comment: sql server or oracle? choose one. and you should check [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: I removed the incompatible tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: So, it seems you are looking for the word "festival" somewhere in the same string? So is it also possible to have a value like "ultra music logistics" or "coachella budget", and you don't want those counted? Then - what about lower case vs upper case; could you have both `ultra music festival` and `Ultra Music Festival`? Is the name of the festival always at the beginning of the string, or might you also have `2016 ultra music festival`? (If it's always at the beginning, you can use `LIKE` in such a way that execution is much faster.)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I'm trying to find the amount of querys for each individual festival as a result.

Comment: I'm new to SQL, trying to describe in java sorry. If I would have this problem in java: I would have 1 array with all the searched querys and in the other one I would have all the festival names. Then i would just have a double loop and would compare every single festival name with every single index of the querys in the other array. If theres a match I would just count up a variable. Trying my best to describe my point. Thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: My questions were "business need" (in plain English)  regardless of SQL or java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
select f.name, count(*)
from querydata qd join
     festivals f
     on qd.query like '%' || f.name || '%'
group by f.name;
```

Note:  This assumes that the names don't have overlaps.  "Christmas" and "Christmas Eve" could result in unexpected duplicates.

Comment: you have `q` as alias but use `qd` in `on` condition

Comment: I don't really know why but I'm just not getting anything as a result

Comment: If the values are not all the same case, then you should use `upper()` or `lower()`.

Comment: Thanks so much this worked out for me. Just had some issues with my database. Really appreciate your effort !

Answer (score 1):

Use `like` as mentioned in other answer or `instr` like below:

```
select t1.name, count(*) 
 from festival t1 inner join Querydata t2 on instr(t2.query, t1.name) > 0 
  group by t1.name;
```